# Instagram video share using hooks

Tags: ios, objective-c, hook, instagram

I want to post a video from camera roll to Instagram with tags. My application uses following code.

```
- (void)share
{
    NSString *Caption = @"#baby";
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"assets-library://asset/asset.mov?id=%@&ext=mov",assetLocalID];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSString *escapedString   = [url.absoluteString URLEncode];
    NSString *escapedCaption  = [caption URLEncode];
    NSURL *instagramURL       = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"instagram://library?AssetPath=%@&InstagramCaption=%@", escapedString, escapedCaption]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:instagramURL];
}

- (NSString *)URLEncode
{
    return [self URLEncodeUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}

- (NSString *)URLEncodeUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding {
    return (__bridge_transfer NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef)self,NULL,(CFStringRef)@"!*'\"();:@&=+$,/?%#[]% ",CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(encoding));
}
```

But caption is not added into instagram. **I wanted to add the tags.**
I have gone through https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/iphone-hooks/, but it didnt help me! Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the idea to allow my app to accept the instagram:// URL schema. The hook from Flipagram opened up in my app as the following:

instagram://library?AssetPath=assets-library%3A%2F%2Fasset%2Fasset.mp4%3Fid%3D8864C466-A45C-4C48-B76F-E3C421711E9D%26ext%3Dmp4&InstagramCaption=Some%20Preloaded%20Caption

The undocumented iPhone hook that allows you to automatically select assets from the iPhones photo roll, and preload a caption for the video. This should give you the same user experience that Flipagrams app has with sharing a video to Instagram.

```
NSURL *videoFilePath = ...; // Your local path to the video
NSString *caption = @"Some Preloaded Caption";
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:[NSURL URLWithString:videoFilePath] completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"instagram://library?AssetPath=%@&InstagramCaption=%@",[assetURL absoluteString].percentEscape,caption.percentEscape]];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:instagramURL];
}
}];
```

Works great!

Update: Instagram has removed the ability to pass the caption to their app. The best solution now it to just copy the desired caption to the paste board.

Comment: removed the ability to pass the caption to their app? So it is not possible to add tags for the video?

Comment: @rishu1992 it is not possible to add tags for the video.